# TypeScript discriminated union between different interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to convert between different interfaces with the same type tag, but TypeScript doesn't seem to understand that the type will remain the same. Here's a minimal reproduction:

```js
type FooItem = {
  type: 'A'
}

type BarItem = {
  type: 'B'
}

type Item = FooItem | BarItem;

type FooThing = {
  type: 'A'
}

type BarThing = {
  type: 'B'
}

type Thing = FooThing | BarThing;

function convert<T extends Item>(item: T): Extract<Thing, { type: T['type']}> {
  return {
    type: item.type
  };
}
```

In the real version, `Item` and `Thing` would have different properties, but I just tried to do the simplest possible reproduction.

To me, it's self-evident that the matching type will be returned but TypeScript throws an error:

```
Type '{ type: "A" | "B"; }' is not assignable to type 'Extract<FooThing, { type: T["type"]; }> | Extract<BarThing, { type: T["type"]; }>'.
```

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Ideally without `as` and without needing to enumerate the subtypes.

Comment: TypeScript can't analyze across unions that way, see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for the relevant issue.  The recommended approach to things like this is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves a significant refactoring to generic indexed operations on mapped types.  For your example code it is [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WyxrZm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I see. I was sure others had run into this, I just couldn't think how to search for it. So I guess the short answer is to map from one union to another, TypeScript can't infer the mapping based on the discriminant but rather it needs an explicit mapped type. I'd need to refactor my real code to make sure it typechecks but this seems like it would solve it.

Comment: So does that mean I should write up an answer or should I wait until you make sure it typechecks in your code and if it doesn't then you'll [edit] the example to be more reflective of the issue?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the real code, so it could be that my example was oversimplified. I haven't forgotten about this; I'll try to follow up with something more reflective soon, just getting through other priorities first.

Comment: Of course you have your own priorities in your life, but as time goes on I will forget more about this. It's already been longer than the normal lifespan of a q/a discussion.  So I hope you don't mind if, when you do respond, there's a chance I won't engage further.

Comment: That's fair. Either way, your example was a step in the right direction, which was helpful for me and might be for others. If you still want to write it up, please do and if need be, I'll ask another question at a later time.